# IRF (stacking) Configuration on HP Comware switches (5130's)

Tags: networking, hp, switch, hp-procurve

I currently have a stack of 6 HP 5130's and would like to add another switch to that IRF stack.

I have everything on the same firmware, etc. but I'm confused as to when to enter the configurations on the new stack member switch- before or after cabling everything up?

There's numerous guides online, and they all describe the process as configuring the new member before cabling it up. HOWEVER, in the example configs they show entering the interface configs on the new member switch as interface 7/0/48 - 7/0/50, but until the switch is in the stack, you don't have an interface 7/0/x, it's interface 1/0/x, do you know what I'm saying?

This is an example procedure:

```
system-view
    irf member 1 renumber 7
    y
    save f
    quit
    reboot
    y
    -STOP----- (after reboot)
    system-view
    interface range  Ten-GigabitEthernet 7/0/49 to Ten-GigabitEthernet 7/0/50
        shutdown
        quit
    irf-port 5/1
        port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet 7/0/49
        quit
    irf-port 5/2
        port group interface Ten-GigabitEthernet 7/0/50
        quit
    interface range  Ten-GigabitEthernet 7/0/49 to Ten-GigabitEthernet 7/0/50
        undo shutdown
        quit
    save f
    irf-port-configuration active
    save f 
    (The device reboots now automatically)
```

*Finally, add the switch to the stack, power up, and connect IRF-cables*

But how can I issue interface commands to interface 7/0/x before the switch is a member of the stack and only has interfaces 1/0/x?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dit you notice the reboot in that command sequence that you included?
The first command puts it in IRF mode as member 7 (regardless  whether it is cabled as such or not).
When it comes back up after the reboot the interface numbering is different.
That is something that the switch can’t do on the fly. That is why you need the reboot after changing the stack member number and when going from non-stack to stack switch (or vice-versa).

Comment: thank you. Can you please confirm- The existing stack does not need to reboot in order for me to add the new member, correct? I can just cable up the new switch into the stack and boot it up? Don't want to bring down the existing stack if i dont have to

Comment: No need to reboot the existing stack. But please make sure you set the extra switch to a unused stack member number and reboot it before you physically attach it to the stack. A colleague of mine found out the hard way that having 2 stack members with the same number is really bad. Whole stack becomes unstable and the config may get corrupted. Worst case you have to rebuild the whole stack.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out-
Once you assign the IRF member ID (7, in my case) the interfaces change from 1/0/x to 7/0/x.